# How to add a second photo to a mailing block

Tags: mailing

How can I change a mailing block to add a second photo

Comment: can you provide some more information on what you trying to achieve?

Comment: I imagine he is looking to add an additional photo in a mosaico block.

Answer (score 1):

Each (mosaico) block is configured for one or more images. If you want a block with a different number of images, choose a different block.

You might be able to trick mosaico into including an image where it's not expecting it, but that would defeat the purpose of what it does for you (i.e. mobile + support for many different mail readers).